# ignore null data insert into sql from datagrid view

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datagrid

im insert data to sql server from data gridview i have problem some null data enter to, how i can make that null data no enter in my tabble and i have some problem to some data no enter to my table.[look image pls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkB0m.png)

```
Using con As New SqlConnection(constring)
    Using cmd As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO kkpsurabaya VALUES(@Emp_No, @AC_No, @No, @Name, @Auto_Assign, @Date, @Timetable, @on_duty, @off_duty, @clock_in, @clock_out, @Normal, @Realtime, @Late, @Early, @Absent, @OT_Time, @Work_time, @Departmen)", con)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Emp_No", row.Cells("Emp No#").Value)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AC_No", row.Cells("AC-No#").Value)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@No", row.Cells("No#").Value)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", row.Cells("Name").Value)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Auto_Assign", row.Cells("Auto-Assign").Value)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", row.Cells("Date").Value)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Timetable", row.Cells("Timetable").Value)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@on_duty", row.Cells("on duty").Value)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@off_duty", row.Cells("off duty").Value)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clock_in", row.Cells("clock in").Value)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clock_out", row.Cells("clock out").Value)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Normal", row.Cells("Normal").Value)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Realtime", row.Cells("Real time").Value)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Late", row.Cells("Late").Value)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Early", row.Cells("Early").Value)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Absent", row.Cells("Absent").Value)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OT_Time", row.Cells("OT Time").Value)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Work_time", row.Cells("Work time").Value)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Departmen", row.Cells("Department").Value)
        con.Open()
        Try
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest doing this a different way.  Instead of looping through the grid and manually inserting each row, create a `DataTable` and bind it to the grid.  You can then make a single call to the `Update` method of a data adapter to save the lot.  You can either use a command builder to generate the `InsertCommand` of the data adapter or do it yourself.  Either way, you don't have to worry about NULLs as it will be handled for you.  Here's an example using a command builder:

```
Private adapter As SqlDataAdapter
Private builder As SqlCommandBuilder
Private table As DataTable

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    adapter = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM MyTable", "connection string here")
    builder = New SqlCommandBuilder(adapter)
    table = New DataTable

    adapter.FillSchema(table, SchemaType.Source)

    Me.BindingSource1.DataSource = table
    Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = Me.BindingSource1
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Me.BindingSource1.EndEdit()

    adapter.Update(table)
End Sub
```

Comment: There's nothing especially complex about it.  If you want me to provide a more specific explanation then provide a more specific explanation of what you don't understand.

Comment: @RiskyWahyuN We can only explain it to you, we cant understand it for you.  That sometimes takes a little old fashioned research.

Comment: i dont know im change form my laptop and do in pc this no eror again.

Answer (score 0):

If row.Cells("Emp No#").Value is null than AddWithValue will leave out this parameter in stead of putting DBNull.Value.
I consider this a huge bug but I seem to be the only one.
Anyway you can fix it like this :

```
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Emp_No", row.Cells("Emp No#").Value ?? (object)DBNull.Value)
```